# UITableview scrolls top when UIView's needsUpdateConstraints is called

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios7, scroll, nslayoutconstraint

Is there any way to stop `UITableView` scrolling on top when `UIView`'s

`needsUpdateConstraints`

method is called. So that selected cell should be visible when i tap on row.

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *viewWidthConstraint;

- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    self.viewWidthConstraint.constant = 540;
    [self.viewForm needsUpdateConstraints];
}
```

Comment: @Andrew Barber: I have explain what needs to be there in question. I think you should put on hold 50% of SO question, if it is so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried setting scrollable to NO?

tableView.scrollEnabled = NO;

After reviewing your question, I have a couple questions about what's going on.

If you are presenting the UIView over the tableView and then setting the UIView's userInteractionEnabled to NO, then the UIView will pass touches to the tableView. You would need to set userInteractionEnabled to YES if you want that view to block interaction with the tableView;

Comment: Actually i need UITableView should be scrollable. This is how all view s stack in.

iPad:

1) UITableView
2) UIView (contains UITableView and one UIButton)
3) UIViewController (Main View)

Also there is no other view over UITableView. The thing happens only when i update constraint of #2 UIView (which contains UITableView as a subview). Also i added auto layout constraints in storyboard.